# Lime slurry crumbling after damp work done

Tags: damp-proof-course

last year we had a company come out to take everything back to brick in our kitchen and added a lime slurry to the wall as we had damp raised in our survey.

This is what they done.
Drill and inject dpc cream to wall area
Tanking slurry to wall area
Lime based render and finish plaster

The guy said that the crystals will appear as it’s drying. Today we’ve noticed this. It’s crumbling and is damp to touch.

We have a solid brick house, so only bricks are behind this. Does anyone have any advice?
Thanks [image]